# ASP.NET MVC First request for static files from a view includes Windows Account credentials, but subsequent requests do not

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, windows-authentication

I have an ASP.NET MVC website that uses both Windows Authentication and Anonymous Authentication.

We're running into an issue where the first request for a static file (the GETs done for the .js/.css-files included on a view with `<script>` or `<style>` tags) use the Windows Domain Account credentials, and subsequent requests use the App Pool Identity. Since the windows identity has no disk access to that website, and no read rights were given to the Authenticated User groups, a 401 is returned for the first out of X .js/.css-files included on a view. The view is protected by an `[Authorize]` attribute on its controller.

It goes like this:

```
GET view (200 OK) 
GET scripts/script.js (401.3 Unauthorized according to ACL)
GET scripts/script2.js (200 OK)
GET content/test.css (200 OK)
```

In the failed request tracing logs on IIS 10 I can see the FILE_CACHE_ACCESS_START operation using the windows credentials for the script.js file resulting in Access Denied, and the app pool identity for the script2.js and test.css files, resulting in an OK.

It's simply always the first request. This 401 also causes a login prompt. Even when cancelled, the request is not retried with anonymous credentials.

Why is this behavior happening? I'd either expect all the GETs to use the Windows User credentials for accessing static files or all of them use the app pool identity. What could be a reason for it being mixed like this?

Please note that I'm not looking for a solution like 'Give the windows user access to the folders' - I'm just wondering why this behavior is happening.